# Webstorm воспринимает директиву v-on как ошибку

Tags: vue.js

Не могу понять с чем связана ошибка директивы v-on.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>App</h1>
        <h1>Count: {{ count }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="countUp" class="btn btn-success"> +1 </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Webstorm выдает следующую ошибку:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28895

Comment: У вас расширение файла компонента `.html`? Vue компоненты должны иметь расширение `.vue`

Comment: а на сокращение для v-on тоже ругается? (@click)

Comment: Да, спасибо, изменил расшерение, Webstorm перестал ругатся. Кстати на сокращение (@click) тоже не ругается. Всем спасибо! :)